# How can I export a table in an html file with php to excel?

Tags: php, html, excel

I want to achieve that by pressing a button this table is exported to excel, that is, an excel file is created with the content of the table.
I have tried with the  `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= archivo.xls");`
but it doesn't do anything it redirects me but it doesn't do the excel
I would like to achieve this goal with this table

**My table is **

```
     
      
        
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre </th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Hora</th>
<th>Entrada</th>
<th>Horario</th>

</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>


    <?php
            $conn = new connection();
            $fechadesde =isset($_GET["fechadesde"])? $_GET["fechadesde"]:null;
            $fechahasta = isset($_GET["fechahasta"])? $_GET["fechahasta"]:null;
            $where='';
            if(!empty($fechadesde) && !empty($fechahasta)){
                $where = " where str_to_date(substring(eb.belgrano_fecha,1,length(eb.belgrano_fecha)-3), '%d/%m/%Y') between '$fechadesde' and date_add('$fechahasta', interval 1 day)";
            }
            $ListadeDatos = $conn->prepare("SELECT eb.belgrano_fecha, eb.belgrano_hora ,CASE WHEN CAST(belgrano_hora as time) <= '08:30' THEN 'Llego a Tiempo Turno Mañana' WHEN cast(belgrano_hora as time) <='15:00' AND cast(belgrano_hora as time) >='11:30' THEN 'Horario de Salida' WHEN cast(belgrano_hora as time) <='18:00' AND cast(belgrano_hora as time) >='16:30' THEN 'Llego a Tiempo Turno Tarde' WHEN cast(belgrano_hora as time) <='21:00' AND cast(belgrano_hora as time) >='19:30' THEN 'Horario de Salida' ELSE'Llego Tarde' END AS salida_entrada, empl.nombre, tes.descripcion FROM `eb_entrada_salida` eb LEFT JOIN empleados_belgrano as empl on empl.id_empleadoBelngrano = eb.rela_empleado_belgrano LEFT JOIN tipo_e_s_belgrano as tes on tes.id_Tipo_E_S_belgrano = eb.rela_tipoE_S_belgrano $where");
            
            $ListadeDatos->execute();
            
           $resultset = mysqli_query($ListadeDatos,$conn) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$developer_records = array();
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
$developer_records[] = $rows;
}
                foreach($developer_records as $rec){
                
                 echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$rec['nombre']."</td>
                        <td>".$rec['belgrano_fecha']."</td>
                        <td>".$rec['belgrano_hora']."</td>
                        <td>".$rec['descripcion']."</td>
                        <td>".$rec['salida_entrada']."</td></tr>";
                            
                       
            }                      
            foreach($ListadeDatos as $l){
                
                 echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$l['nombre']."</td>
                        <td>".$l['belgrano_fecha']."</td>
                        <td>".$l['belgrano_hora']."</td>
                        <td>".$l['descripcion']."</td>
                        <td>".$l['salida_entrada']."</td></tr>";
                            
                       
            } 

      
                                                      
    ?>
    

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but when I need to create an excel file from any DBT, I use this script ;

```
$servername = "IP Address";
$username = "Username";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ExampleTable";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 

$file_ending = "xls";
$filename = "Example";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo $property->name . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   

}
```

**Since that probably isn't it, here's what I saw online.

Step1: Create MySQL Database Table. As we will implement live example to export HTML Table data to CSV, Excel and Text file, so first we will create table developers to store developer data. ...
Step2: Include jQuery, Bootstrap and tableExport Files. ...
Step3: Display Records in HTML Table. ...
Step4: Export HTML Table Data.**